# Rails case statement and flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, flash

I am trying to add flash msg Bootstrap 3 haml in rails 5 app. Only the flash-info in the else part of the case statement is displaying no matter what. What is wrong with my code

```
module ApplicationHelper

def twitterized_type(type)

case type.to_s

    when :errors
        "alert-danger"
    when :alert
        "alert-danger"
    when :error
        "alert-danger"
    when :notice
        "alert-success"
    when :success
        "alert-success"
    when :warning
        "alert-warning"
    else
        "alert-info"
    end

end
```

flash message in application.html.haml

```
.container

    - flash.each do |type, message|
        .alert.alert-dismissable{ :class => twitterized_type(type) }
            = message
            %button.close{ data: { dismiss: 'alert' } } x
```

Controller:

```
def create
@pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
if @pin.save
  # Display success flash message then redirect to the saved pin
  flash[:success] = 'New pin saved successfully'
  redirect_to @pin
else
  # Display a fail flash message and render new
  flash[:alert] = 'New pin failed to save, please try again'
  render 'new'
end


 def update
if @pin.update_attributes(pin_params)
  # save update and display success flash message
  flash[:success] = 'Pin was updated successfully'
  redirect_to @pin
else
  # flash error message and redirect to edit
  flash[:alert] = 'Pin failed to update, please try again'
  render 'edit'
end
```

How to make the flash displayed with the intended class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **type.to_sym**  in application helper instead of **type.to_s**